# Correct data type with Swagger/Springfox when property has @XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, swagger, springfox

I have annotated an endpoint with swagger annotations. In the @ResponseHeader I set the returning class as response. This class contains a property which is annotated with @XmlJavaTypeAdapter. The adapter is changing the data type of the property. Unfortunately Swagger shows the type of the property, not the return type of the Adapter. Is it possible to do this?

What I already tried is to annotate the property with @ApiModelProperty(). But it was not possible for me to set the dataType to List (Primitive data types or just a list was working).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The following was not working:

```
@ApiModelProperty(dataType = "List<Map<String, String>>")
public Map<String, String> someMap = new HashMap<>();
```

I had to create an Interface

```
public interface ListOfMap extends List<Map<String, String>> {}
```

And then I used this interface in the ApiModelProperty:

```
@ApiModelProperty(dataType = "ListOfMap")
public Map<String, String> someMap = new HashMap<>();
```

With this, everything worked :)